# how to search a word from varchar(comma separated) field in mysql?

Tags: mysql

i have a table

#### table_movie

```
    mid  muid   actor_name          movie_list(varchar)
    18  act_6   tom hanks       mov_18,mov_19,mov_2,mov_22,mov_23 
    21  act_9   jhonny depp     mov_1,mov_10,mov_20,mov_22,mov_3,mov_9
    28  act_16  bruce willis    mov_18,mov_19,mov_2,mov_22,mov_23 
    29  act_19  jhon trovolta   mov_1,mov_10,mov_20,mov_22,mov_3,mov_9
```

now i want to dispplay only those `actor_name` and `muid` which have `mov_1`( which comes from php) in their `movie_list`

if i use `EXIST` then it show error, my query is written below

```
    `SELECT muid,actor_name FROM table_movie WHERE $movieID EXIST( movie_list)`
```

i also tried with `RLIKE` but no results!:(

please tell me how to search a single word from a varchar field

#### NOTE

my table engine is INNODB so fultext search concept also fails

Comment: well, my first comment is maybe you could restructure that table to something normlaized - queries will be much simpler.

Comment: what structure i shoud prefre?

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
SELECT muid,actor_name FROM table_movie WHERE movie_list LIKE '%,$movieID,%'
OR movie_list LIKE '%,$movieID'
OR movie_list LIKE '$movieID,%'
OR movie_list LIKE '$movieID'
```

?

Edit: I modified the query to take the comments into account. A bit ugly but I guess it would work. Forget about performance. Another problem would be titles with comma in it.

If you can modify the schem you could have a 'movie' table and a 'actor_movie' table.

Comment: Although, if `$movieID` were contained in another movie title/id, you might run into problems...depends on your required functionality.  If you search for "tar wars" (case-insensitive), should you get back all of the Star Wars movies too?